# hmacSHA384 from C#

Tags: c#, .net, hmacsha1

I have a code.PHP code, that generates sha384 hash string.similar to the below code.

```
$hash=hash_hmac(“sha384”, $aid .
          $amount .
          $version .
          $currency .
          $mid .
          $mode.
          $request .
          $responsetype, 
          $key);
```

I want to generate this hash code hmacSHA384 from c#.
I tried in several ways. but that didn't work as I expected.

```
string val = string.Concat( int aid, int amount, string version, string currency,int mid, string mode, string request, string responsetype);

private static byte[] hmacSHA384(string val,string key)
            {
                using (HMACSHA384 hmac = new HMACSHA384(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key))
                {
                    return hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(val));
                }
            }
```

how should I convert this?

Comment: I followed normal c# hmacSHA384 generate code.if you look at my code.

In c# I used the only key parameter. I haven't used any other parameters here.so how should I add remaining parameters?

as a byte array or??

Comment: That PHP concatenates all of the parameters together (presumably as a string?) before hashing the result. I suggest you try to find an example of exactly what is being hashed, so you can write a test case in C#.

Comment: Yes, that concatenation is correct. I modified my answer according to that.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you'll have to convert each item to string before you can concatenate them. You have a few options:

1. call `.ToString()` on each value then concatenate the strings, e.g.

   ```
   string val = aid.ToString() + amount.ToString() + ...
   ```
2. use String.Format (C#'s printf-like function) to construct the string

   ```
   string val = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}[3}{4}{5}{6}{7}", aid, amount, ... );
   ```

   which will render each value as a string as it goes.
3. but the new string interpolation syntax is probably the easiest way:

   ```
   string val = $"{aid}{amount}{version}{currency}{mid}{mode}{request}{responsetype}";
   ```